# CoreText with multicolumn with image?

Tags: ios, swift, ipad, core-text

I want to design like below:

[image]

I am using `core text` to draw a `multicolumn`, i can show it up, thats not problem, need to show image as static like image,
First three column need to show, the fourth column will show by scrolling horizontal.

> 1.Need to add hyper link to video url.
>
> 2.Need to design like above..

**Sample tried with two ways:**
https://github.com/karthisiva/CoreTextWithImage

The content will be **html text**.

Comment: Is this possible in doing WebView with CSS?